# How do I fix underfull hbox when using custom command?

Tags: macros, minipage

I've written a small command so that I don't have to keep creating `minipage`s. The command is defined as such:

```
\newcommand{\itemimage}[3][]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item #2
        
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#1]{#3}
    \end{minipage}
}%
```

Any time I use this, it seems to generate a warning for "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph"

```
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    %...
    \itemimage[width=300px]{This is just some text.}{img001.png}
    %...
\end{enumerate}
```

However, if I don't use the command, and instead use what the command is, then no warning is generated.

```
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    %...
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item This is just some text.
        
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=300px]{img001.png}
    \end{minipage}
    %...
\end{enumerate}
```

What am I missing from my `\itemimage` command to prevent these warnings from occurring?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\newcommand{\itemimage}[3][]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item #2

        \centering
        \includegraphics[#1]{#3}
    \end{minipage}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \itemimage[width=300px]{This is just some text.}{img001.png}
    
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item This is just some text.
        
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=300px]{img001.png}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code & Warning]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, sorry about that, I've included a working example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your MWE gives two overfull hboxes, one for each minipage. The problem is that  your image is too wide. If you make the width 300px, for example, there are no overfull hboxes.

Comment: @Andrew, changed it to 300px widths for the images, and the overfull is gone, but the underfull is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to omit spaces at ends of lines, you were generating a line with just a word space which can not stretch to fill the line hence the underfull box. (note you can use `example-image` in examples as these images are distributed for such tests)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\newcommand{\itemimage}[3][]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item #2

        \centering
        \includegraphics[#1]{#3}
    \end{minipage}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
    \itemimage[width=300px]{This is just some text.}{example-image.png}
    
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item This is just some text.
        
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=300px]{example-image.png}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```